# Transpile TSX to MJS for React files with ESM Node and Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, es6-modules

I'm working on a Node application entirely developed with ESM and Typescript, therefore Typescript files have the extension .mts and imports are of this type:

```
import { some } from 'some.mjs'.
```

In one part of my code I make use of **renderToStaticNodeStream** of **react-dom/server** like this:

```
const { index }: any = await import('./templates/index');
const html = renderToStaticNodeStream(index);
```

In the templates/index.tsx file is where the React code is:

```
import React from 'react';

export function Index() {
   return(
     <div>
       <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
       <p>This is the index template.</p>
     </div>
   );
}
```

The problem is that when I transpile my application, all the .mts files are correctly transpiled to .mjs files, however the .tsx file stays as .js and I need it to be transformed to .mjs as well.

Is there a way to fix this with the Typescript transpiler?